Unity/Vuforia - VuMark & Image Marker positions reported incorrectly on HoloLens 2 even when they are tracked in view
I'm having a problem on HoloLens where on rescanning a marker Vuforia sometimes reports the position relative to the camera rather than the world origin.

Using delayed initialisation, we initialise vuforia and then scan a VuMark, the position is reported correctly.

After disabling and then re-enabling the vuforia behaviour, and then scanning the marker again, occasionally (maybe 1 in 4 attempts) the marker position is briefly reported correctly but then immediately jumps to a position that seems to be relative to the camera rather than the world origin.


I've tried manually resetting the device pose behaviour and disabling/enabling the marker behaviour and using both TRACKED and EXTENDED TRACKED but the problem persists.
Logs from HoloLens 2 device
Unity Version: 2022.3.15f1
Vuforia Version: 10.13.3
Repro Steps

Initialise Vuforia.
Scan VuMark
Marker is found in correct position
VuforiaApplication.Instance.GetVuforiaBehaviour().enabled = false
Wait for a period
VuforiaApplication.Instance.GetVuforiaBehaviour().enabled = true
Scan VuMark

Expected: Marker is found in the same position as step 3.
Actual: Marker is found but the position is incorrect (sometimes), and seems to be a relative offset from the camera

SO is not the right place for bug reports. I would suggest to file it here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues
